# Grails rest using urlmapper, how to remove class name for rest request

Tags: rest, grails

I created a rest server. Using POST method, I send the following data:

```
{"class":"abc.User","email":"me@gmail.com"}
```

To make sure it work, I use curl:

```
curl --request POST --data '{"class":"abc.User","email":"me@gmail.com"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8081/abc/api/add
```

The problem arise when I create rest client to send data. I use rest-client-builder plugin.

My code for client is:

```
def resp = rest.post("http://localhost:8082/abc/api/add"){

contentType "application/json"

json {
    class = "dsi.ewallet.prepaidserver.Kartu"
    email = "me@gmail.com"
}
```

}

I got error: "unexpected token"
If I remove the 'class' , it fix the problem. But my rest server need to pass class name.

Is there anyway to fix it? Or how to remove the need to pass class name for rest server? Thanks.

Comment: I guess class is a reserved work, can you call it "className" or "clazz" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide to use `JSONBuilder()`

```
def builder = new JSONBuilder()
String result = builder.build() {
    setProperty("abc", abcValue)
    setProperty("def", defValue)
}
return result
```

When I need to construct more complex structure, I create groovy class that contains only the attributes. Then populate the data to that class and use it with `JSONBuilder()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is class is reserved word in java as you can use `Class.class` or `this.getClass()`, so it is making problem while parsing, so I think you have to change the name of this attribute.

it is working with curl because it is not using java